# How to extract hash keys in given order?

Tags: perl, data-structures

I have next hash:

```
%hash =  (
  name => {
     pos => 1
  },
  name_xxx => {
     pos => 2
  },
  name_yyy => {
     pos => 3
  },
)
```

And want to construct next array (keys must be ordered by `pos`):

```
qw/ name name_xxx name_yyy /
```

I suppose I should do [Schwartzian Transform](https://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=9108)

**What is the shortest and/or fastest way to extract hash keys in given order?**

Comment: Despite this having been answered pleas note that Stack Overflow should not be the place where you come to get someone to write your code for you.

Comment: @JGNI: Why you decide that this is my homework? I know how to accomplish this ( I even dig deep perl internals while writing [debugger](https://github.com/KES777/Devel-DebugHooks) ) I just wanna to see different ways how to do this. In any case this question seems to me interesting also will be helpful for novices

Comment: Err... I didn't mention homework, I don't know or care how old you are. However it is general policy on Stack Overflow that you provide some code in the question that attempts to do what you are asking.

Comment: @JGNI: Updated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you have is not a hash, it's a hash reference (with missing commas). To get the keys, use [keys](http://p3rl.org/keys) and dereference:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my $hash_ref = {
    name     => {pos => 1},
    name_xxx => {pos => 2},
    name_yyy => {pos => 3},
};

my @keys = sort { $hash_ref->{$a}{pos} <=> $hash_ref->{$b}{pos} }
           keys %$hash_ref;
print "@keys\n";
```

Comment: Sorry. The order of keys is defined by `pos` (I have updated the question and spell this explicitly)

Comment: @EugenKonkov: Updated.

Comment: Er he has a hash `%hash =  ()` is creating and assigning to a hash.

Comment: @JGNI: He didn't when I wrote the reply.

Comment: OK, in that case I apologise for the down vote, sorry.

Comment: @JGNI: You should be able to take it back :-)

Comment: I can't I guess not enough rep to take it back

Comment: @JGNI I must say, I find that a strange reason to vote down.  Everything in the answer stands even if that (hash vs hashref) were off.

Comment: @JGNI: For the algorithm it has not matter the type of data: hash or hashref. Before downvote you can ask people to clarify that part you do not understand or not sure.

Answer (score 3):

Just use `keys` and `sort`

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use warnings;
use strict;

my %hash =  (
  name => {
     pos => 1
  },
  name_xxx => {
     pos => 2
  },
  name_yyy => {
     pos => 3
  },
);

my @sorted_array = sort { $hash{$a}{pos} <=> $hash{$b}{pos} } (keys %hash);

print "@sorted_array", "\n";
```

It will sort numerically by the pos value.

Answer (score 1):

The shortest way is to use [List::UtilsBy](https://metacpan.org/pod/List::UtilsBy), which internally does a Schwartzian transform for most of its functions. However, it will probably be slower in this case because hash access is fast and it adds extra overhead over a standard sort(). The case where it could be faster is if you sort by, for example, the result of a slow subroutine call.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use List::UtilsBy 'nsort_by';
my %hash = (
  name => {
     pos => 1
  },
  name_xxx => {
     pos => 2
  },
  name_yyy => {
     pos => 3
  },
);
my @sorted_keys = nsort_by { $hash{$_}{pos} } keys %hash;
```